# Error when trying to use a RecyclerView - why?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a new Android Studio developer and I am studying how to use RecyclerView but it seem I can't make it work using all the tutorials I searched both on google and youtube. Below errors are showing when I try to run the code I copied on this website - https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b

Please help. I'm using the latest AndroidStudio version.

Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.itbscorp.testrecycler, PID: 18467
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itbscorp.testrecycler/com.itbscorp.testrecycler.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.itbscorp.testrecycler-kbheTQbZQdBBMxi8OmT9Ew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.itbscorp.testrecycler-kbheTQbZQdBBMxi8OmT9Ew==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.itbscorp.testrecycler.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class Model {
    public String mId, mTitle, mDesc;

    public Model() {

    }

    public Model(String mId, String mTitle, String mDesc) {
        this.mId = mId;
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
        this.mDesc = mDesc;
    }

    public String getmId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setmId(String mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public String getmTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    public String getmDesc() {
        return mDesc;
    }

    public void setmDesc(String mDesc) {
        this.mDesc = mDesc;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>a
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Model.java

```
public class Model {
    public String mId, mTitle, mDesc;

    public Model() {

    }

    public Model(String mId, String mTitle, String mDesc) {
        this.mId = mId;
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
        this.mDesc = mDesc;
    }

    public String getmId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setmId(String mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }

    public String getmTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    public String getmDesc() {
        return mDesc;
    }

    public void setmDesc(String mDesc) {
        this.mDesc = mDesc;
    }
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Description" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

build.grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itbscorp.testrecycler"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: Add more details with code, layout and gradle

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: The problem seems to be in the project's dependencies as it is not finding the RecyclerView in the classpath: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path. Add your build gradle's dependencies to the question.

Comment: Posting codes. Please wait

Comment: You are using Androidx component but recyclerview is of 'android.support.v7'

Comment: replace `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` with `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

Comment: @RadekJ man did not see that. xml file is wrong. thank you!

Comment: @AngeloDayao check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using the android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, which is outdated and also not included in your project.

Either make sure to include android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in your build.gradle or refactor by using the androidx recyclerview library.

for the old support library use:
`implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`

For AndroidX:
`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'`
and change android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in your xml with androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

you should change 
`android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` in your xml to `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.`

and in your project dependencies check if you set the right one for recyclerview

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'`

Comment: @AngeloDayao Remember, please, that on Stack Overflow the accepted way to thank for a contribution that answers your question is to click the check mark at the answer's left. That will let others know the question has been answered and also award site points to the person who made the effort to write it up :-)

Comment: No need to add dependency for RecyclerView, CardVIew, in androidX just add this dependency **`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`**